# jquery scroll() and on(mousemove) messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this function to hide my `header` when scrolling down, and showing it again when scrolling up

```
$(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $('.item').scroll(function() {
        var nowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nowScrollTop) >= delta){
            if (nowScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                $('header').fadeTo(0,0); // scrolling down
            } else {
                $('header').fadeTo(0,1); // scrolling up
            }
            lastScrollTop = nowScrollTop;
        }
    });
});
```

Additionally I'm using this function to show the header when the cursor is in the top 200px of the page:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ( e.pageY < 200 ) {
        $('header').fadeTo(0,1);
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I'm scrolling with my mouse being in the top 200px of the window, the two functions collide, and the header keeps toggling between being shown and hidden.

Now, I've read elsewhere that I need to unbind and bind the mousemove when scrolling. I don't know however how to do that.

EDIT:

Here's a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrmg646L/

EDIT 2:

Here's a link to the jsfiddle with the solution in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zrmg646L/3/

Comment: Jquery's [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) can be applied where you need it.  Could you make a fiddle of this so folks can see your issue in action?

Comment: Hi, I've added a link to a fiddle now, in the bottom of my original question

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Unbind mousemove on scroll and rebind it after not scrolled for 250ms

```
 function fadeHeader(e) {
       if ( e.pageY < 200 ) {
             $('header').fadeTo(0,1);
           }
  }

$(function(){
         $(window).mousemove(fadeHeader);
         var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
         $('.item').scroll(function() {
            $(window).unbind('mousemove', fadeHeader);
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                     $(window).mousemove(fadeHeader);
            }, 250));

        var nowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nowScrollTop) >= delta){
            if (nowScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                $('header').fadeTo(0,0);                    
            } else {
                $('header').fadeTo(0,1); // scrolling up
            }
            lastScrollTop = nowScrollTop;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't working. Nothing happens actually. The header doesn't hide on scroll down, or anything.

Comment: I'm very sorry, it IS working. I messed up when pasting back, I guess. Thank you very much !